# Android: VideoView not working on some devices

Tags: android, android-videoview

I have a `VideoView` that works with a lot of devices but not on others. For some time it shows my `ProgressDialog` and then it fires a Popup that says **Impossible to play video** (translated from Italian, so it may be different but... you understand).

For example it works on Samsung Galaxy S:

- Android version: 2.2.1
- Kernel version: 2.6.32.9

But not on HTC Magic

- Android version: 2.2
- Kernel version: 2.6.34.5

The video I want to show is taken from a URL and it'an MP4 file.

Here's the code:

```
public class VideoViewActivity extends BaseActivity {

    ProgressDialog progDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Uri videoUri = Uri.parse(getIntent().getStringExtra("url"));
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_view);
        VideoView vv = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        vv.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
        vv.requestFocus();
        vv.setVideoURI(videoUri);
        vv.start();

        if (app.isEnglish()) {
            progDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, getResources().getString(R.string.en_wait), getResources().getString(R.string.en_load), true);
        }
        else {
            progDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, getResources().getString(R.string.it_wait), getResources().getString(R.string.it_load), true);
        }


        progDialog.setCancelable(true);
        vv.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                progDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

That's the layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".VideoViewActivity" >

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoView"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: it might be the resolution of the video.

Comment: I'm trying to change the resolution of the video... will make you know

Comment: Nothing... I've tried a lot of different resolutions and codecs... nothing works for HTC Magic with CyanoGen Mod 6.0.0!

Comment: @aveschini did you manage to fix it? I am facing the same situation now.

Comment: Sorry @kabuto178, I ended up calling the youtube app to show the videos...

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same iisue while using videoView. I managed it using device's installed media application using intent. They are doing there application for managing media, Why we want to waste our time...

```
PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
                    Intent videoIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    videoIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(videoUrlLink),
                            "video/*");
                    List listOfSuppApps = packageManager
                            .queryIntentActivities(videoIntent,
                                    PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
                    if (listOfSuppApps.size() <= 0) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                getResources().getString(R.string.No_supported_applications_Installed),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {

                        Intent intnt = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intnt.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(urlLink), mediaType+"/*");
        context.startActivity(intnt);
                    }
```

The above is my code

Comment: Nope... the video still doesn't play with other apps... I think it's a problem with the codec or the resolution.